# How to checked the checkbox if amount <1 in Angular data table? Should I write a function?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, datatable

I am trying to create an inventory App with Angular 11 and I have some fields in the Angular table like amount, name, status, etc. I can update and create (not yet delete)
When I edit a product, if I set an amount <0, the status should be checked. This means out of stock.
Should I create a new function from ts file or how can I use *ngIf is it fine?

[this explains the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnjUw.png)

````
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 30%">Status</th>
            <th style="width: 30%">StockCode</th>
            <th style="width: 30%">Name</th>
            <th style="width: 30%">Amount</th>
            <th style="width: 30%">Updated At</th>

            <th style="width: 10%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let pro of product">
            <td> <input type="checkbox" *ngIf="pro.amount<1" >In Stock</td>
            <td>{{pro.stockCode}}</td>
            <td> {{pro.name}}</td>
            <td>{{pro.amount}}</td>
            <td>{{pro.lastUpdatedAt}}</td>
            <td>
                <a routerLink="edit/{{pro.id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-1">Edit</a>
                <!-- <span (click)="deletePro(pro.id)" class="text-danger">Delete</span> &nbsp; -->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="!product">
            <td colspan="4" class="text-center">
                <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-lg align-center"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>```
````

Comment: `<input (click)="false" type="checkbox" [checked]="pro.amount<1" >`? I add `(click)="false"` to not allow change it -you can add also "disabled" but the checkbox will be gray-. You can also add a icon like a checkbox checked

Comment: thank you it was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to use (checked) event. I have created a sample project taking your code. Refer to this link [Working demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-onwo1g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Hope this helps. If this helps, don't forget to accept this answer.